# Update Binding from DataGrid Group

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a WPF with a DataGrid and I group rows (by "Name" in the example). I would like to have summary row for each group ("Name" and the total "Amount" which I calculate in a Converter).
The problem is that when I update a data value ("Amount" in the example), the summary row is not updated.
So, I would like to force binding update of the summary row but I cannot access it as far as it is in a DataTemplate.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource posCurrencyOpen}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount"  Binding="{Binding Amount, Converter={StaticResource Amount_Converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <DataGridCell Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <DataGridCell Content="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource AmountGroup_Converter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Does your `Amount` property fire a `PropertyChanged` event when set? If not, your UI won't update. Keep in mind that in WPF generally, firing `PropertyChanged` = asking the view to update itself =)

Comment: Yes, Amount property fire a PropertyChanged which actually update my database. And my database is updated, so I think the PropertyChanged works

Comment: PropertyChanged has nothing to do with your actual database. Could you add the code where you initialize the Amount in C# ?

Comment: Ok I implemented a PropertyChanged event on my entity but not on the ObservableCollection and I had to. I do and know it works. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Anthony Did you find a solution to your problem?